# get value from empty locked field

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have users who can submit either a new person or a new category, if they check a radiobutton for add person they can enter all the fields except category, if they check the category radiobutton they can only enter information in the category box. I controll enable and disable via jquery:

```
  $j("#addCat").click(function(){
     $j("#personnal-option-category").prop('disabled', false);      
     $j("#personnal-option-group").prop('disabled', true);
     $j("#personnal-option-position").prop('disabled', true);
     $j("#personnal-option-interests").prop('disabled', true);  
     $j("#personnal-option-phone").prop('disabled', true);  
     $j("#personnal-option-email").prop('disabled', true);          


});

$j("#addPersonell").click(function(){
     $j("#personnal-option-category").prop('disabled', true);       
     $j("#personnal-option-group").prop('disabled', false);
     $j("#personnal-option-position").prop('disabled', false);
     $j("#personnal-option-interests").prop('disabled', false); 
     $j("#personnal-option-phone").prop('disabled', false); 
     $j("#personnal-option-email").prop('disabled', false);         


});
```

If no category has been filled out do this:

```
<?php if(count($cat) == 0 ||  { ?>
do stuff here
```

if category has been filled out do this:

```
<?php if(count($cat) > 0){ ?>
```

However when I disable the field or hide it with jquery it seems to not pass on any value at all. I dont want the field to be visible and editable because I do not wish for a person to be able to add both a category and a person at the same time (for various reasons).

How can i edit my logic when to run the code when no category has been added? 
Kind regards, Emil

Answer (score 0):

I found it. replaced

```
 <?php if(count($cat) == 0 ||  { ?>
```

with

```
<?php if(empty($cat)) { ?>
```